# Select2 Tags: Add email format tags in input after keypress "Enter", "Space", "Tab"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one `input`

```
     <label id="email2_error">Email is not in the correct format</label>

     <input type="text" style="width:500px" id="emailTags" placeholder="add email" />
```

after keypress I call method addTag

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $("select#emailTags").select2({
             placeholder: "JohnDoe@example.com",
             allowClear: true
         });

 jQuery("#emailTags").keypress(function (event) {

                   //See if the key pressed is 'space'
                   if (event.which == 32) {
                       addTag();
                   }
                   //See if the key pressed is 'enter'
                   if (event.which == 13) {
                       addTag();
                   }
                   //See if the key pressed is 'tab'
                   if (event.which == 8) {
                       addTag();
                   }

               });

    });



           function addTag() {

               var email = $('#emailTags').val()
               if (!validateEmail(email)) {
                   $("label#email2_error").show();

                   return false;
               } else {

                   $("label#email2_error").hide();
                   //Adding the tag
               $('#emailTags').select2('val', $('#emailTags').val());
               }
 function validateEmail(email) {

                var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                return re.test(email);
           }
      </script>
```

the tag is not added, some proposal?

Comment: Shouldn't you be putting the regular expression inside a quote?

Comment: @ISuthanBala method validateEmail work fine, in console I tested and it work ok

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution just you need to change a script

```
if (self.isOpen()) {
    if (key === KEYS.ENTER) {
      self.trigger('results:select');

      evt.preventDefault();
    } else if ((key === KEYS.SPACE && evt.ctrlKey)) {
      self.trigger('results:toggle');

      evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (key === KEYS.UP) {
      self.trigger('results:previous');

      evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (key === KEYS.DOWN) {
      self.trigger('results:next');

      evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (key === KEYS.ESC || key === KEYS.TAB) {
      self.close();

      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  } else {
    if (key === KEYS.ENTER || key === KEYS.SPACE ||
        ((key === KEYS.DOWN || key === KEYS.UP) && evt.altKey)) {
      self.open();

      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

replace with

```
if (self.isOpen()) {
    if (key === KEYS.ENTER || key === KEYS.TAB) {
      self.trigger('results:select');

      evt.preventDefault();
    } else if ((key === KEYS.SPACE && evt.ctrlKey)) {
      self.trigger('results:toggle');

      evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (key === KEYS.UP) {
      self.trigger('results:previous');

      evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (key === KEYS.DOWN) {
      self.trigger('results:next');

      evt.preventDefault();
    } else if (key === KEYS.ESC || key === KEYS.TAB) {
      self.close();

      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  } else {
    if (key === KEYS.ENTER || key === KEYS.TAB || key === KEYS.SPACE ||
        ((key === KEYS.DOWN || key === KEYS.UP) && evt.altKey)) {
      self.open();

      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```